# How to end loop if value does not change for X consecutive seconds in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, time

I am collecting data from a potentiometer connected to an Arduino. In the script, I tell matlab to keep collecting data for 2 minutes. But I need to tell it that if the user does not move the potentiometer for 10 consecutive seconds, then it should stop the loop and move to the next session (write the data to an excel file). Does anybody have ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Your code so far?

Comment: How do you tell how long you've been collecting data? Can you show the code for your loop?

Comment: This is my code so far:
`trigOnset0 = GetSecs;
t0 = clock;
j=0;
while etime(clock,t0)<=blockDuration    
    if etime(clock,t0)>= blockDuration/2 && etime(clock,t0)<= (blockDuration/2)+2
        disp '2 minutes OVER'
        play(Audio);
    end
    
    j=j+1;
    potValues(j,1) = readVoltage(a, 'A0')* (1023 / 5);
    
    timeAxis(j,1) = etime(clock,t0);    
end`

Comment: Notes: 
1) I am trying to format the code for better reading, but failing.
2) This is only a small part of the code. I wanted to post all of it but it said it was too long.
3) What I need to do is: record for 2 minutes (stimulation time). After the two minutes, keep recording from the pot BUT stop if the participant did not move the pot for X seconds (I think 15 seconds should do it).

Comment: Don't post your code in the comments. Add it by clicking `edit` button right under your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [`tic`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) and [`toc`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) can help you.

`tic` starts a stopwatch timer. The function records the internal time at execution of the `tic` command.

`toc` reads the elapsed time from the stopwatch timer started by the `tic` function.

```
tic;
while toc < 10
    % Do your loopy things
    if variable_changed
        tic; % Restart stopwatch
    end
end
```

Furthermore to be sure `tic` won't interact with other processes you should store it's value like this:

```
% First start stopwatch
time_since_last_movement = tic;
while toc(time_since_last_movement) < 10
    % Do your loopy things
    if variable_changed
        time_since_last_movement = tic; % Restart stopwatch
    end
end
```

Comment: Good approach, however you should use the return value of `tic`, that way the timer won't be interact with other users of `tic` and `toc`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I was kind of working on a similar concept.
Anyway, I tried your approach and it worked =) 
Thank you very much, I really appreciate...